# Yii2. Border in Html::a after Modal window close

Tags: css, modal-dialog, yii2

My modal window opens after click on user icon:

```
echo Html::a('<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-user" aria-hidden="true"></span><span class="badge badge-notify">444</span>',
 ['#'],
 ['id' => $model->id,
 'class' => 'linkbutton',
 'data-toggle'=>'modal',
 'data-tooltip'=>'true',
 'data-target'=>'#search'.$model->id,
 'title'=> 'Votes']);
```

When Modal is opened all is OK. A tooltip dissapears and no border in user icon visible. But after close Modal some border appears. It dissapears after I click on any place of webpage.
[image]

How to remove them automatically after Modal close?
I tried to add css border:none!important on focus and visited but no success:

```
.linkbutton{
     background:none!important;
     border:none; 
     padding:0!important;
     cursor: pointer;
     color: darkcyan;
     font-size: 15px;

}

.linkbutton:hover {
    color: #ccc;
    text-decoration: none;
}

.linkbutton:visited .linkbutton:focus{
    border:none!important; 
}
```

Comment: check also for linkbutton:selected

Comment: border is still appears